# How do you play a lower or upper mordent with two notes like in Bach D minor prelude 926?

Tags: baroque-period, j-s-bach

How do you play these two mordents shown

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Piano mordent with two notes](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/7870/piano-mordent-with-two-notes)

Answer (score 1):

These two are [lower mordents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordent), meaning a quick and single alternation with the note below it, meaning, for the second example, playing A G A quickly, with F remaining unaffected.

For more infos you can refer to the link @BrianTowers gave you, or also [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/72676/what-notes-in-these-mordents), which is not exactly the same but could give you some hints.

Comment: Thank you, by unaffected, you mean that I hold F throughout the whole A G A process. In the first example, I also hold A throughout the whole process as well

Comment: Yes, of course! the mordent is only concerning the higher voice, the eighth note.

Comment: @rene Albrecht was faster ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, are mordents also played exactly on the beat. like in the first picture, it would be AC# B C# With A sustained but the AC# must be played on beat 1 then with a quick B C#. So that beat 2 starts with E

Comment: Sorry I meant beat 2 to start on C# not E

Comment: @Rene Yes exactly!